# Is it possible plot the function $h(x;a,b,c)$ over $0<x<3$ for numeric triplets $(a,b,c)$?

Tags: plotting, numerics, multivalued

I have a constraint `f[a_, b_, c_] ==0` with three parameters $-1<a,b,c<1$ where

```
f[a_, b_, c_] = b^6 + 16 b^5 c + 4 (25 - 2 a) b^4 c^2 + 16/3 b^2 (84 + 3 (-26 + a) a - 8 c) c^4 -  16/3 b^3 c^3 (-57 + 18 a + c) +  64/3 b c^5 (12 + 6 (-6 + a) a + (-6 + a) c) + (64/9) ( c^6) (36 (-2 + a) a + 12 (-2 + a) c + c^2)     ;
```

On the other hand, I have the function `h[x_, a_, b_, c_]` with $0<x<3$ as follows

```
h[x_, a_, b_, c_] =  Exp[ -c/x - x Sqrt[c^2/(9 (b + 4 c)^2)] ] (x)^(1 + b/( 2 c)) (1 + (2 a)/c x);
```

**My Question.**

> I want to numerically solve `f[a_, b_, c_] ==0` and find the list of its solutions as the triplets $(a,b,c)$ on the domain $-1<a,b,c<1$. Then, having obtained those numeric triplets, I want to plot the function `h[x_, a_, b_, c_]` over $0<x<3$ for those $(a,b,c)$. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: `f[a_,b_,c_]:=b^6+16 b^5 c+4(25-2 a)b^4 c^2+16/3 b^2(84+3(-26+a)a-8 c)c^4-16/3 b^3 c^3(-57+18 a+c)+64/3 b c^5(12+6(-6+a)a+(-6+a)c)+(64/9)(c^6)(36(-2+a)a+12(-2+a)c+c^2);
h[x_,a_,b_,c_]:= Exp[-c/x-x Sqrt[c^2/(9(b+4 c)^2)]]x^(1+b/(2c))(1+2 a/c x);
h3[{a_,b_,c_}]:=h[x,a,b,c];
points=N[{a,b,c}/.FindInstance[f[a,b,c]==0&&-1<a<1&&-1<b<1&&-1<c<1,{a,b,c},10]];(*find 10 numeric triplet (a,b,c) solutions*)
Quiet[Plot[Map[h3,points],{x,0,3}]](*Plot h curve for 0<x<3 for each of those 10 (a,b,c) numeric triplet solutions*)`

Comment: The solution of  "f[a, b, c] ==0" are not discrete triplets but a 2 dimensional surface. Therefore, h[x, a, b, c] is defined on a 3 dimensional volume.

Comment: @Bill Thank you very much for the helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here I show how to create the array for use with `ListDensityPlot3D` and `ListSliceDensityPlot3D`

definition `f[], h[]` (I changed the arg-list in h-function!)

```
f[a_, b_, c_] := 
  b^6 + 16 b^5 c + 4 (25 - 2 a) b^4 c^2 + 
   16/3 b^2 (84 + 3 (-26 + a) a - 8 c) c^4 - 
   16/3 b^3 c^3 (-57 + 18 a + c) + 
   64/3 b c^5 (12 + 6 (-6 + a) a + (-6 + a) c) + (64/
      9) (c^6) (36 (-2 + a) a + 12 (-2 + a) c + c^2);
h[ a_, b_, c_, x_] := 
  Exp[-c/x - 
     x Sqrt[c^2/(9 (b + 4 c)^2)]] (x)^(1 + b/(2 c)) (1 + (2 a)/c x);
```

First we evaluate all triples `a,b,c` using `ContourPlot3D`

```
pic = ContourPlot3D[f[a, b, c] == 0, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}, Mesh -> False]
abc = pic[[1, 1]][[1]];
```

[image]

Now add x-grid `0<x<3`

```
abcx = Table[Join[u, {x}], {u, abc}, {x, Subdivide[1/100, 3, 10]}] //Flatten[#, 1] &;
```

Create final grid `b,c,x,h`

```
bcxh = Map[Join[Rest[#], {Apply[h, #]}] &, abcx] // N; 
Dimension[bcxh] (* {340989, 4} *)
```

Format of `bcxh` is ok but h-values are very large:

```
bcxh [[All, 4]] // MinMax (*{-3.45262*10^6, 1.43243*10^42}*)
```

Plot result

```
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[bcxh, "CenterPlanes" ]
```

[image]

Due to the scaling of `h` plot result doesn't look promising. Perhaps check your `h-function`